# Adding an eventhandler in javafx through a custom class

Tags: java, events, javafx, event-handling

I had very big eventhandling methods in my controller class. I placed each of them in a separate class but now they're not getting called anymore.

This is how it's currently implemented:

```
private DragDetectedHandler dragDetectedHandler = new DragDetectedHandler(stacks, nextCards, gameTable);;
node.setOnDragDetected(dragDetectedHandler);
```

If I call this it works:

```
node.setOnDragDetected(System.out::println);
```

(Just to test that the code is reached)

And the handler class:

```
public class DragDetectedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
private Stacks stacks;
private NextCards nextCards;
private Table gameTable;

public DragDetectedHandler(Stacks stacks, NextCards nextCards, Table gameTable) {
    this.stacks = stacks;
    this.nextCards = nextCards;
    this.gameTable = gameTable;
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("Handle stuff here :)");
}
}
```

I'm probably overlooking something but similar questions didn't help me get my answer.

So the question: How should I call the event handler? Or why does the following code not call the event handler?

```
node.setOnDragDetected(dragDetectedHandler);
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include... well... a question?

Comment: @JoeC Thanks, I forgot to actually ask the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out this code and found it to work for me.

To try to find what could be wrong is you could check what you are importing and make sure it if javafx and not swing or awt.

Here is what I tried:

```
package test;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class DragDetectedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

private String test;

public DragDetectedHandler(String test) {
    this.test = test;
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("Handle stuff here :)");
}
}
```

and the other class:

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test2 extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test2.launch(args);     
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    DragDetectedHandler dragDetectedHandler = new 
       DragDetectedHandler("Test");
    Button button = new Button();
    button.setOnDragDetected(dragDetectedHandler);
    Scene scene = new Scene(button);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, apparantly I was calling it before the constructor got called for the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

the `Node` should be **enabled** so that the event will work.

i tried this code , it's work when i drag the rectangle :

```
public class Main extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        DragHandler dh = new DragHandler();
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200 , 200 , 200 ,200);
        rect.setOnDragDetected(dh);
        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane , 600 , 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private class DragHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, apparantly I was calling it before the constructor got called for the event handler.